# Why does this std::function and operator cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I don't see anything wrong with this code but it gives me a seg fault. Changing the std::function to a normal function solves the problem. Also removing the addition in the overloaded operator solves the problem. Also changing the Point constructor from const int& to int solves the problem. But I don't understand why.
https://onlinegdb.com/Sy32UTllO

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    Point() {}
    Point(const int& x, const int& y) {}
};
Point operator+(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) { return {p1.x+p2.x, p1.y+p2.y}; }
Point p1, p2;
std::function<const Point&()> fn = []{ return p1; };

int main()
{
    Point p3 = fn() + p2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p2` isn't initialized?

Comment: change the ctor to Point() : x{}, y{} {} to ensure that objects of Point are initialized by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::function<const Point&()> fn = []{ return p1; };
```

Because you didn't specify the return value of the lambda, it defaults to returning it *by value*. So `fn` is trying to return a reference to a temporary, which is undefined behavior.

Do this instead:

```
std::function<const Point&()> fn = []() -> const Point& { return p1; };
```

Comment: Oh. Does std::function<const Point&()> not specify the return type?

Comment: I see. It does, but the lambda doesn't. Right?

Comment: Treat the lambda and `std::function` as separate things (because they are). The return type of the `std::function` and the return type of the lambda are not related. The lambda returns `p1` by value, and then the `std::function` tries to return a reference to that value.

Answer (score 2):

`[]{ return p1; }` returns by value, so `fn()` returns a dangling reference.